# Can bots that crawl my site click links to delete my posts?

Tags: php, mysql, bots

I have a website with a Content Management System built with PHP (no framework) and mySQL database. On my site's backend, I have buttons to delete posts. Recently I lost almost all of my posts (around 150 of them), they were deleted from the database. I know it wasn't me who deleted them, and the other people who had access claim they didn't either.

I've looked through the logs but I was not able to find any useful leads; however, I did find that a number of bots crawl through my the site. This brings me to my question:

Is it possible that the bots could've 'clicked' the delete button when they were going through the site?

Comment: The only way would be if they logged into your website, and deleted your content as an authenticated user since I assume you don't allow unauthorized unauthenticated users to delete content.

Comment: Access to the backend requires login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the bots could've 'clicked' the delete button when they were going through the site?

Yes, depending the bot (automated software).

However, the bot would:

- Need to be "programmed" to "click" any buttons it found.
- Likely need to have proper login credentials (though a bot using a loophole in the security of the site itself  to gain elevated privileges is also theoretically possible).